# How to make two SQL queries really asynchronous

Tags: c#, multithreading, ado.net, task-parallel-library, async-await

My problem is based on a real project problem, but I have never used the `System.Threading.Tasks` library or performing any serious programming involving threads so my question may be a mix of lacking knowledge about the specific library and more general misunderstanding of what asynchronous really means in terms of programming.

So my real world case is this - I need to fetch data about an user. In my current scenario it's financial data so let say I need all `Accounts`, all `Deposits` and all `Consignations` for a certain user. In my case this means to query million of records for each property and each query is relatively slow itself, however to fetch the `Accounts` is several times slower than fetching the `Deposits`. So I have defined three classes for the three bank products I'm going to use and when I want to fetch the data for all the bank products of certain user I do something like this :

```
List<Account> accounts = GetAccountsForClient(int clientId);
List<Deposit> deposits = GetDepositsForClient(int clientId);
List<Consignation> consignations = GetConsignationsForClient(int clientId);
```

So the problem starts here I need to get all those three list at the same time, cause I'm going to pass them to the view where I display all users data. But as it is right now the execution is synchronous (If I'm using the term correctly here) so the total time for collecting the data for all three products is:

```
Total_Time = Time_To_Get_Accounts + Time_To_Get_Deposits + Time_To_Get_Consignations
```

This is not good because the each query is relatively slow so the total time is pretty big, but also, the `accounts` query takes much more time than the other two queries so the idea that get into my head today was - "What if I could execute this queries simultaneously". Maybe here comes my biggest misunderstanding on the topic but for me the closest to this idea is to make them asynchronous so maybe then `Total_Time` won't be the time of the slowest query but yet will be much faster than the sum of all three queries.

Since my code is complicated I created a simple use case which I think, reflect what I'm trying to do pretty well. I have two methods :

```
public static async Task<int> GetAccounts()
{
    int total1 = 0;
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connString))
    {
        string query1 = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [MyDb].[dbo].[Accounts]";
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query1, connection);
        connection.Open();
        for (int i = 0; i < 19000000; i++)
        {
            string s = i.ToString();
        }
        total1 = (int) await command.ExecuteScalarAsync();
        Console.WriteLine(total1.ToString());
    }
    return total1;
}
```

and the second method :

```
public static async Task<int> GetDeposits()
{
    int total2 = 0;
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connString))
    {
        string query2 = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [MyDb].[dbo].[Deposits]";
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query2, connection);
        connection.Open();
        total2 = (int) await command.ExecuteScalarAsync();
        Console.WriteLine(total2.ToString());
    }
    return total2;
}
```

which I call like this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine(GetAccounts().Result.ToString());

    Console.WriteLine(GetDeposits().Result.ToString());
}
```

As you can see I call `GetAccounts()` first and I slow the execution down on purpose so I give a chance the execution to continue to the next method. However I'm not getting any result for a certain period of time and then I get all printed on the console at the same time.

So the problem - how to make so that I don't wait for the first method to finish, in order to go to the next method. In general the code structure is not that important, what I really want to figure out is if there's any way to make both queries to execute at the same time. The sample here is the result of my research which maybe could be extended to the point where I'll get the desired result.

P.S
I'm using `ExecuteScalarAsync();` just because I started with a method which was using it. In reality I'm gonna use `Scalar` and `Reader`.

Comment: You should be using `await connection.OpenAsync();` so the connection set up is done async as well.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

When you use the `Result` property on a task that hasn't completed yet the calling thread will block until the operation completes. That means in your case that the `GetAccounts` operation need to complete before the call to `GetDeposits` starts.

If you want to make sure these method are parallel (including the synchronous CPU-intensive parts) you need to offload that work to another thread. The simplest way to do so would be to use `Task.Run`:

```
static async Task Main()
{
    var accountTask = Task.Run(async () => Console.WriteLine(await GetAccounts()));
    var depositsTask = Task.Run(async () => Console.WriteLine(await GetDeposits()));

    await Task.WhenAll(accountTask, depositsTask);
}
```

Comment: @I3arnon I think I don't get something. My original idea was to get the result in different moment of time. From your description I think that maybe like this the total time is equal to the slowest time, but when I added to the second method `for (int i = 0; i < 19000000; i++)
                    {
                        string s = i.ToString();
                    }` the time doubled. Which is strange. If it was simultainously and since in this case the queries takes milliseconds I was expecting the same time as when only one of the methods is slowing down.

Comment: I'm not sure if I make myself clear. My idea is that if `GetAccounts()` takes 3 secs and `GetDeposits()` less than sec I expect  3 sec to get result. But if I force `GetDeposits()` to execute for 3 secs instead of getting again 3secs, because this is the slowest time and the task are executed at the same time I get the result after 6secs. this is pretty much what happen if I try this   approach as it is. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Leron asynchronous is not the same as parallel. Your methods have both an asynchronous part and a synchronous part (I/O and CPU). You can easily have the asynchronous parts execute concurrently, as they do in my answer. To make the synchronous part execute in parallel you need to use 2 threads with `Task.Run`. Is that what you want?

Comment: `Memory usage limit was exceeded` - I get this error too fast so I can't really simulate what I do here. To be fair I'm not sure what `parallelize` stands for. But if you don't mind edit with example.

Comment: @Leron `async-await` enables you to release a thread instead of blocking it throughout an asynchronous operation. It doesn't make the synchronous parts (e.g. a for loop) execute simultaneously with other synchronous parts (e.g. the other for loop). To do that you need multiple threads. I gave an example using Task.Run

Comment: Gonna go out. Will look at your answer as soon as I'm home. Thanks a lot for the support!

Comment: Sorry to resurrect an old question, but the title _is_ "How to make two SQL queries really asynchronous". IMO, if the queries are asynchronous, and the rest of the code is not, that satisfies the original question.

To clarify, one could also write something along these lines:

    `var accountTask = GetAccounts();`
`var depositsTask = GetDeposits();`

    `await Task.WhenAll(accountsTask, depositsTask);`

    `// Do something with the results.`

The SQL part will still be executed in parellel, correct?

Comment: @BryanRayner they will be executed concurrently. But the synchronous part of these methods will run sequentially.

Answer (score 8):

Here's a way to to perform two tasks asynchronously and in parallel:

```
Task<int> accountTask = GetAccounts();
Task<int> depositsTask = GetDeposits();

int[] results = await Task.WhenAll(accountTask, depositsTask);

int accounts = results[0];
int deposits = results[1];
```

Comment: In connection string must be specified "MultipleActiveResultSets=True"

https://dapper-tutorial.net/knowledge-base/46163437/getting-the-connection-does-not-support-multipleactiveresultsets-when-using-dapper-simplecrud-in-a-foreach

Comment: @Pažout You actually wouldn't need to do that because the OP isn't reusing a single connection between both calls.  Each task has it's own connection to the database.

Answer (score 4):

I generally prefer to use Task.WaitAll. To setup for this code segment, I changed the GetAccounts/GetDeposits signatures just to return int (`public static int GetAccounts()`)

I placed the Console.WriteLine in the same thread as assigning the return to validate that one GetDeposits returns before GetAccounts has, but this is unnecessary and probably best to move it after the `Task.WaitAll`

```
     private static void Main(string[] args) {

        int getAccountsTask = 0;
        int getDepositsTask = 0;
        List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>() {
            Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {
                getAccountsTask = GetAccounts();
                Console.WriteLine(getAccountsTask);
            }),
            Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {
                getDepositsTask = GetDeposits();
                Console.WriteLine(getDepositsTask);

            })

        };
        Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());



    }
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Can you provide me with some guidelines on how to get more information about what you just did?

Comment: Note that `Task.WaitAll()` has return type `void` so if tasks return something you won't get the result. To get it you need to use `await Task.WhenAll()`.

Comment: This isn't asynchronous at all. It's 2 completely synchronous operations being executed in parallel.

Comment: @Leron, [Task.Factory.StartNew](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321439(v=vs.110).aspx) creates a new task and starts it immediately performing the anonymous method `() => {
                getAccountsTask = GetAccounts();
                Console.WriteLine(getAccountsTask);
            }`. Task.WaitAll() pauses the thread's execution until all tasks in the array have completed. As L3arnon pointed out, these are synchronously/parallel running tasks (assumed this was closer to what you wanted based on context)

Comment: @abatishchev since the tasks are stored in an array, you can get the results from the execution by enumerating through `tasks`, however the wanted result (the int value from `ExecuteScalar`) is returned directly to member variables (`getAccountsTask` and `getDepositsTask`) and doesn't rely on execution information from the Task.

Answer (score 0):

If it's ASP.NET use AJAX to fetch after the page is rendered and put the data in a store. Each AJAX fetch is asynchronous. If you want to create simultaneous SQL queries on the server?

Usage:

```
 // Add some queries ie. ThreadedQuery.NamedQuery([Name], [SQL])
 var namedQueries= new ThreadedQuery.NamedQuery[]{ ... };

 System.Data.DataSet ds = ThreadedQuery.RunThreadedQuery(
 "Server=foo;Database=bar;Trusted_Connection=True;", 
 namedQueries).Result;


 string msg = string.Empty;
 foreach (System.Data.DataTable tt in ds.Tables)
 msg += string.Format("{0}: {1}\r\n", tt.TableName, tt.Rows.Count);
```

Source:

```
public class ThreadedQuery
{

    public class NamedQuery
    {
        public NamedQuery(string TableName, string SQL)
        {
            this.TableName = TableName;
            this.SQL = SQL;
        }
        public string TableName { get; set; }
        public string SQL { get; set; }
    }
    public static async System.Threading.Tasks.Task<System.Data.DataSet> RunThreadedQuery(string ConnectionString, params NamedQuery[] queries)
    {

        System.Data.DataSet dss = new System.Data.DataSet();
        List<System.Threading.Tasks.Task<System.Data.DataTable>> asyncQryList = new List<System.Threading.Tasks.Task<System.Data.DataTable>>();

        foreach (var qq in queries)
            asyncQryList.Add(fetchDataTable(qq, ConnectionString));

        foreach (var tsk in asyncQryList)
        {
            System.Data.DataTable tmp = await tsk.ConfigureAwait(false);
            dss.Tables.Add(tmp);
        }

        return dss;

    }

    private static async System.Threading.Tasks.Task<System.Data.DataTable> fetchDataTable(NamedQuery qry, string ConnectionString)
    {
        // Create a connection, open it and create a command on the connection
        try
        {

            System.Data.DataTable dt = new System.Data.DataTable(qry.TableName);
            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
            {
                await connection.OpenAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Connection Opened ... " + qry.TableName);
                using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(qry.SQL, connection))
                {
                    using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Query Executed ... " + qry.TableName);

                        dt.Load(reader);

                        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("Record Count '{0}' ... {1}", dt.Rows.Count, qry.TableName));

                        return dt;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {

            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Exception Raised ... " + qry.TableName);
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);

            return new System.Data.DataTable(qry.TableName);
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Async is great if the process takes a long time. Another option would be to have one stored procedure that returns all three record sets.

```
        adp = New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
        dst = New DataSet
        adp.Fill(dst)
```

In the code behind of the page, reference them as dst.Tables(0), dst.Tables(1), and dst.Tables(2). The tables will be in the same order as the select statements in the stored procedure.

Comment: Can you please update your answer with correct syntax?